# Is it okay to write tasked yield return like this?

Tags: c#, .net

We know that we can use `yield return` to return an element in an iterator method, for example:

```
public IEnumerable<int> MyMethod(){
    yield return 0;
    ...//Lots of code here;
    yield return secondResult;//Just for illustration
}
public void Main(){
   foreach(int i in MyMethod()){
       DoSomething();
   }
}
```

In the code written above, `MyMethod()` will stop execution when ever reaching `yield return` until request for next result of the `foreach`, which is, in this case, every completion of `DoSomething()`.
I think, as the `DoSomething()` and `MyMethod()` are actually independent to each other, it is possible to make them executing in parallel. This would be increasingly considerable if those two methods are calculation-massive.
What am I trying to do look like this:

```
public IEumerable<int> MyMethod(){
    Task<int> task = GetNextAsync();//Prepare for next return
    yield return 0;
    yield return await task;
}
```

It this fine? Is there anything wrong or what should I be careful for?

Comment: You cannot use `await` in a non-async method.

Comment: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/09/iasyncenumerable-in-c-8/  IAsyncEnumerable would work better here.

Comment: What is the actual goal? Iterator blocks used to be (miss)used as a form of co-routine. But  today Tasks/async/await mostly fulfill the same purpose in a better way.  If you are not using the results from `MyMethod` there is probably some other pattern that is a better fit.

Comment: `async` and paralelism are two separate things. Neither implies the other.

Answer (score 0):

> It this fine?

No, because it won't compile.

You are trying to implement an [async iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8), which needs to return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, as well as using the `async` keyword to enable `await`:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> MyMethodAsync()
{
    Task<int> task = GetNextAsync();//Prepare for next return
    yield return 0;
    yield return await task;
}
```

> Is there anything wrong or what should I be careful for?

Only that this needs to be consumed using `await foreach` rather than a standard `foreach`:

```
await foreach (var i in MyMethodAsync())
```

Or you can use [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async)